# Keep getting "missing return statement" error

Tags: java, methods, return

I am very new to any sort of programming and am learning java. I have a task but keep getting errors and am unsure how to solve. Would appreciate any help as this task is much more complex than any I have attempted. 
The main issues i'm having is using multiple methods and using return.

This is my code so far if it makes any sense to anyone... Any help appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LPU {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean gradedep;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please input your mark: ");
            int mark = in.nextInt();        

            System.out.println("Please input number of days to display: ");
            int days = in.nextInt();

        if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 100 && days >= 0 && days <= 20) {
                gradedep = true;

        } else {
               System.out.println("");
               System.out.println("");
               System.out.println("Please re-enter as you have entered an invalid input.    ");
               System.out.println("");
               System.out.println("");
               gradedep = false;
        }
        } while (!gradedep);
        }

    public static int mingrade(int mark, int days) {
        int newmark;

        if (mark < 40 && mark >=0) {
            newmark = mark;

        } else { 
            newmark = mark - 5;

        return newmark;
        }
    }
}
```

LPU.java:40: error: missing return statement
        }
        ^
1 error

I am aware this error is to do with some nonsense in the code but am unsure how to correct it.

Comment: Move your `return` outside the `else` braces.

Comment: It looks like you want `return newmark` to be **outside** of the `else` branch.

Comment: A tip for the future, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Just a small tip: make your IDE reformat code for you. It will fix indentations and you will see clearly if your return statement is misplaced.

Answer (score 3):

Move the return statement outside of the else clause, like this:

```
    public static int mingrade(int mark, int days) {
        int newmark;

        if (mark < 40 && mark >=0) {
            newmark = mark;
        } else { 
            newmark = mark - 5;
        }

        return newmark;
    }
```

The way you have it in your post, if the mark is less than 40 and greater than or equal to 0, newmark is set, but never returned.

There's also no need to instantiate the `newmark` variable. This would be a cleaner approach:

```
    public static int mingrade(int mark, int days) {
        if (mark < 40 && mark >=0) {
            return mark;
        } else { 
            return mark - 5;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
// delete newmark
if (mark < 40 && mark >=0) {

   return mark;
} else { 

    return (mark -5);
}
```